# How can I bulk-change the color of text in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I’ve got a twenty-page document; each page has six text boxes on it with no other content. I want to change the text colour of all text, including the text boxes.

Is there a simple way I can do this ?

I believe you can assign a class to text, a bit like CSS, so you can make changes like this in one go, but I have not done it for this file.

I’m running InDesign 2017 CC.

Comment: Have you tried  Character Colour in the Paragraph Style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe you can assign a class to text (a bit like CSS) so you can make changes like this in one go...

Oh absolutely!
They're called paragraph styles and using them is definitely one of the 10 Indesign commandments! Maybe the 1st one ^^  (see https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html)

Anyway, since you haven't used them, you can use the Find/Replace feature to apply one.
Question is: what is common to all your texts? Color maybe?

Let's imagine you got black text and you want it blue.
Use the Find/Replace feature to "catch" all black text and... change it to blue?

Possible but... nooo!!! Apply a paragraph style (set to blue text) instead...

See example below. Of course, in my example, all black text will be changed, so you have to figure out what specs make your text unique. Could be a combination of many things (color, font size, font name, etc...)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. It saved me going through all my 100+ paragraph styles to check

Answer (score 0):

i have like 10 paragraph styles and only want to make one page where they're all white instead of black. but i don't want to have to manage an entire set. it's like 20 text boxes, and i'm not even sure i'm going to use it, so it would be such a huge waste of time unless i can just say "ok, all of you are white now"